What is this conditional?

The next morning Dodo was driving me to Silent Hill, and if I was to run away before it was too late, now was the time.


So, why not_ now would be the time_, so it would be second conditional? Or it does not matter and it just another example of english chad native speakers mentally dominating on virgin english learners?

"Was driving" bc future in the past? Could i say: The next morning Dodo are driving me to Silent Hill, and if I was to run away before it was too late, now would the time?



*.... would be the time" in 2. question. Or can i say "... and if I am to run away before it is too late, now will be the time?" Would it mean the same thing? –

This question is similar to: how many conditional sentence types are possible?. tchrist writes 'Last time I counted them, I found two hundred and seventy-seven English conditionals. There are of course others.' Expecting them all to have a label is a pipedream. ESL texts in general grossly oversimplify. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

1 - The next morning Dodo was driving me to Silent Hill, and if I was to run away
but before it was too late, now was or would have been the time." 2 - No future in the past showing.

@YosefBaskin sorry, sir, but if it's not for future in the past, why author uses past continuous here talking about future? "The next morning Dodo was driving me to Silent Hill..."

I think this is trying to emulate a nonstandard dialect that uses "was" for many different tenses. I expect you'll find something like this in books like Huckleberry Finn.

"The next morning Dodo was driving me" is all in the past. Not a single moment, a process, but all in the past. Not future.

I don;t think there's anything "non-standard" about using now was the time in the cited context. Now would be the time strikes me as pedantic verbiage for the sake of it.
